# MySQL query with AJAX calls executing really slowly

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

is there any way to reduce the time between the AJAX call and its result? I use it to call a php page which executes some queries on a database with 3 tables (416608,7490 and 366 rows).
For example, here are some queries:

```
SELECT r.id,ROUND(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,c.time,r.time)),2) as avg
FROM requests r RIGHT JOIN clicks_214 c ON r.id=c.rid 
WHERE r.hid='$hid'
GROUP BY c.rid
ORDER BY avg DESC
LIMIT $limit,50;
```

Or

```
SELECT r.ua, count(c.rid) as cnum, count(r.kwd) as rnum
FROM requests r LEFT JOIN clicks_214 c ON r.id=c.rid
WHERE hid='$hid' 
AND r.time BETWEEN '$date1 $hour1:00:00' AND '$date2 $hour2:00:00'
GROUP BY r.ua
ORDER BY rnum DESC
LIMIT $limit,50;
```

And there are some more, but similar to those.
Is there any way to reduce that 1.6/3.5 minutes time to get the results of the AJAX call?
Searched on this forum but I didn't got a real answer to my problem, I've seen something like avoid the use of `"NOT IN"` or `"!="`, which is not my case

Comment: Have you tried running an `EXPLAIN` to see how MySQL is fetching those rows? It could be you need to add some indices.

Comment: do you really need to load such huge data on page. Its not good idea to load so much data. Use paging.

Comment: On the surface this doesn't seem to be anything to do with it being an AJAX call but just a slow running MySQL query. If you hit the php page directly i.e without jQuery/AJAX does it perform just as slow? If so it might be worth editing your tags

Comment: Is it possible to cache the result of such a query ? Do you have indexes ?

Comment: I've tried executing those queries directly on PHPMyAdmin and it takes the same time, with AJAX takes just 0.5 seconds more

Comment: @Machavity ,is it possible to add indices in mySQL ?

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird Yes, and they're pretty essential (I think MySQL calls them indexes in the plural, but potato potahto). Google `mysql indexing`.

Comment: @Machavity thank you, i've set some high used columns as indexes and AJAX time has become 6 seconds